# Сменить тип объектов в generic списке

Tags: java, алгоритм, generics

Пишу класс для сортировки объектов по полю имя. Предполагаю работу с разными типами, поэтому использую generic

```
public static <T> List<T> sortStringList(List<T> list, Class type){

    List <Integer> numList = new ArrayList();
    for (T item : list) {
        if (item.getClass() == type && type == SubCategory.class)
        {
            System.out.println("It subcategory");

        }
        if (item.getClass() == type && type == Category.class) {


        }
    }


  return list; 
}
```

В условии я определил с каким именно типом я работаю, а вот как теперь в list сменить T на необходимый мне тип? То есть чтобы у меня был например list с элементами типа Category. Нужно мне это для того чтобы обращаться к полям объекта  Category.

Comment: Явно привести элемент списка к нужному типу? `((Category) list.get(0)).categoryMember`?

Comment: Да, верно, про приведение типов я просто не знал. Спасибо!

Comment: Если решение верное – нажмите, пожалуйста, на галочку рядом с ответом.

Comment: Но вообще, вы должны помнить, что подобные выкрутасы, говорят о проблеме в проектировании класса.

Answer (score 7):

Чтобы обратиться к полю/методу, Вы должны сначала явно преобразовать элемент списка к Вашему типу:

```
((Category) list.get(0)).categoryMember
```

Но вообще, по-моему мнению, исходная задача сортировка решается другим способом.

---

**В дополнении к данному ответу, опишу способ, который я имел ввиду выше.**

Этот способ заключается в реализации интерфейса `Comparable` объектами, наборы которых будут сортироваться.

Предположим, есть некий объект – животное, которое имеет параметр – вес. Необходимо отсортировать список животных по возрастанию их веса. Для выполнения этой задачи создадим класс `Animal`, реализующий интерфейс `Comparable`:

```
public class Animal implements Comparable {
    private float mWeight;

    public Animal(float weight) {
        mWeight = weight;
    }

    public float getWeight() {
        return mWeight;
    }

    public void setWeight(float weight) {
        mWeight = weight;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        float diff = this.mWeight - ((Animal) o).mWeight;
        if (diff > 0)
            return 1;
        else if (diff < 0)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Теперь мы может отсортировать набор таких животных с помощью `Collections.sort(...)`:

```
List<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
animals.add(new Animal(10.3f));
animals.add(new Animal(10.1f));
animals.add(new Animal(10.2f));
Collections.sort(animals);
```

Comment: Но в моей задаче надо отсортировать строки как числа, то есть сейчас сортировка работает так : А.1 Первая категория А.10 Десятая категория   А.11 Следующая категория А.2 Вторая категория. Нужно взять цифры из строк, отсортировать их и поменять местами объекты в списке категорий.

Comment: @ЕгорПодоляк, Эта задача решается аналогичным образом.